# best practice to write app both for ios4.3, ios5 and ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

I am just started write app for ios.
I have 2 questions.
I know there are some codes which work fine in ios4.3 but don't work in ios5 and the opposite is also true.I want to know,which is the best practice for writing app  both for ios4.3 and ios5?Is it acceptable run-time to check the version for specific parts of code??

I am also should write same app for ipad. So, I want to know which is the best practice for writing app for iphone which works also on ipad??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**iOS 5 or iOS 4**

Another way to detect the version is to use the `respondsToSelector:` message on objects. The advantage compared to the `version` method is that you don't need to know what the next versions of iOS are gonna be to maintain your application. (What if, for instance, a new 5.0.2 version shows up? Your app should know that the "5.0.2" string is newer than "5.0"? I agree it would not be complicated to code, but using `respondsToSelector:` is much more convenient)

**iPhone/iPod Touch or iPad**

My usual way to code universal app (ie iPhone and iPad) is to define a basic implementation of my custom UIViewController classes, and then implement an HD version of it, inheriting the default behavior but customizing it for the iPad (overriding methods works well but the delegate pattern might be better: you get compilation warnings if you forget to implement methods).

If you use a different .xib file from the beginning of your application lifecycle (that's what you get by universal Xcode-provided templates), you may end up defining classes just from Interface Builder, and won't need to implement any runtime test in your code to know if you're running on an iPhone or an iPad.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the version using:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
```

The systemVersion returns a string, like "5.0". You can then compare the strings using string comparison. For example:

```
NSString *requiredVersion = @"5.0";
NSString *currentVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if ([currentVersion compare:requiredVersion options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
            isItSupported = TRUE;
```

The documentation indicates that you can use the following to determine if you have an iPhone or iPad:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
```

I've not used this though.
See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html).